# function invertNumerSubstrings didn´t work

Tags: c, string, char, ansi-c

I have this problem in Ansi C

3 Create a function that receives an array of strings of 20 characters each decode, considering the following: 
a. Reading it from left to right, the digit indicates how many characters, from there, to be invested (between characters to invest can be digits, to that effect,
   are considered common characters).
b. The digit characters should be replaced with the first character of the string reversed.

Example. The string aj5pr2*dfkl3abc2qwe1azk must be ajd*2rpfklcbawqeazk

Use notation and pointer arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAM 20


char* invertNumerSubstrings(char*);

int main()
{
    char chain[TAM];
    printf("\n Ingrese chain: ");
    gets(chain);
    fflush(stdin);
    char result;
    result=invertNumerSubstrings(chain);
    printf("\n Chain modified: ");
    puts(chain);
    printf("\n");   
    return 0;
}

char* invertNumerSubstrings(char* chain)
{
    int flag =0;
    char *pl= chain;
    char *pe= chain;
    char aux;
    while(*pl=='\0'&& *pe=='\0');
    {
        if(!(*pl=='1')&&(*pe=='9'))
        {
            pl++;
            pe++;
        }
        else
        {

            if(flag ==0)
            {
                pe=*pl;
                flag=1;
                pl--;
            }
            if(*pe<*pl)
            {
                aux=*pl;
                *pl=*pe;
                *pe=aux;
            }
        }
    }
    return *chain;
}
```

This program don´t have compiling errors but didn´t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of problems in your code. Pointing some of them. In function `main()`

```
char result;
result=invertNumerSubstrings(chain);
```

return type of function `invertNumerSubstrings` is `char*` which doesn't match with `result`'s type.

```
while(*pl=='\0'&& *pe=='\0');
```

`;` in above statement is logically incorrect which may results in infinite execution of loop in case condition got satisfied. `*pl=='\0'&& *pe=='\0'` condition is not looking perfect according to need of question (Please correct me if i am wrong).

```
return *chain;
```

The return statement is last statement of function `invertNumerSubstrings` whose return type doesn't match with `char*`.

To get the desired output,   you can try this:

```
void invertNumerSubstrings(char* chain)
{

char *pl= chain;
char* chain_ptr=chain;   // chain_ptr to hold starting address of chain
char* final=(char*)malloc(sizeof(chain));
char* final_ptr=final;  // // final_ptr to hold starting address of final
memset(final, '\0', sizeof(chain));

while(*pl!='\0')
{

    if(*pl>=49 && *pl<=57) //
    {   
         int shift=*pl-48; // to find the shift amount
         int i=0;
         *pl++;

         for(i=shift-1; i>=0; i--){
             *final=*(pl+i);
             final++;
         }
       pl=pl+shift;  // seek the pointer to correct position            
    }

     else
         {
              *final=*pl;
               pl++;
               final++;

         }
}

chain=chain_ptr; // assign original address of chain to chain again

while(*final_ptr !='\0'){
      *chain=*final_ptr ;
      final_ptr++;
      chain++;             
}
*chain='\0';

free(final);

}
```

Assumption: when an integer number is encountered in string then its subsequent string is having length atleast equal to value of integer.

Answer (score 1):

This have compiler warning when I try it - in `main()` you have declared

`char result; result=invertNumerSubstrings(chain);`

but that function is of type `char*`. But then you don't even use `result`.

More seriously, in the function you have put `while(*pl=='\0'&& *pe=='\0');` Note the bad trailing `;` This statement will execute forever if `chain` has no content, but only once otherwise, after which the following code block will be executed once only.